# How to access records after using RowFilter on DataGridView?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, datagridview, dataset

I have a DataGridView which I have used `RowFilter` on it like following:

```
(dgv.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = whereClause;
```

Before applying the `RowFilter` the `DataGridView` has **1087** records and afterwards, it has about **8**.

Now I want to work on those 8 records.

How can I access them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do

```
dgv.DataSource as DataTable
```

Then you can do the following

```
dataTable dt = dgv.DataSource as DataTable;
DataRow[] rows = dt.Select("your filter goes here");
```

You can do same thing by Linq if you want to. These are your rows and you can work with them. And to Edit only these records do:

```
DataGridView.DataSource = rows;
```

Also, you can create a custom `DataView`, which will filter records the way you want it, and set datasource to that view. But remember, the key here, no matter how many views you have - this is same dataTable that you looking at

```
DataView view = new DataView();

view.Table = dt;
view.RowFilter = "your filter";
view.Sort = "your sort";
```

Comment: this gives me the Rows in DataRow but i want to have the records after RowFilter and change some of them in DatagridView while still in Filter mode

Comment: @nnmmss I am not sure what do you mean. What is the difference where you apply the filter? If you want to see these records in DataGridView then do `DataGridView.DataSource = rows`

Comment: @TS:in that case i lose all 1087 records and I just have 8 filtered records. for having all those 1087 reocords i should get it from database. is that true?

Comment: @nnmmss YOu lose nothing. Your records all in DataTable. You just bind grid to subset. As a matter of fact, you will be referencing to the records that exist in your datatable. And if you change one, your table will be changed. You go ahead and try. And see the effect

Comment: @TS:I think that is not true, if i set DataGridView.DataSource = rows; after then the totla number of DataGridView records is 8 records but in (dgv.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = whereClause; it is 1087 records , which when i use (dgv.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = null the whole 1087 are shown again.

Comment: @nnmmss "I think that is not true". Yes, your data source will be 8 records that you want to modify. But when you want to see all, you simply switch datasource to dataview, datatable, etc. You said, " I want to work on those 8 records. ". So work on them! And when you done, click some button and change the data source and see all the records. I think, you only know one way how to work with DataSources when in fact, there are many - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DataGridViewRow.DataBoundItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.databounditem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to access to the underlying data.
If your `DataGridView` bound to the `DataView` the underlying data is of type `DataRowView`. You can use code like this:

```
var dataRow = dgv.Rows[rowIndex].DataBoundItem as DataRowView;
```